# proving 5 is a divisor of x, such that x = $d_1d_2d_3$...$d_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $x$ is a positive integer with $n$ digits, say x = $d_1d_2d_3$...$d_n$

Prove that if $d_n$ = 0 or $d_n$ = 5, then 5 is a divisor of x

It seems obvious that if the last number is a 5 or 0, that 5 is a divisor of that number, i am just having trouble proving it.

Comment: To be pedantic, your claim assumes the digits are in decimal (base ten). This result is not true for other bases. For example, in base six, the integer eleven has the representation $15$, but five isn't a divisor of eleven.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that $x$ can be written as $10y + r= 5(2y)+r$ where $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r \in \{ 0, 5\}$.

Now consider $2$ cases, case $1$: $r=0$ , case $2$: $r=5$.

Answer (score 1):

$x=\overline{d_1d_2...d_{n-1}d_n} =10\times \overline{d_1d_2...d_{n-1}} + d_n$

Certainly $5$ divides $10\times \overline{d_1d_2...d_{n-1}}$; so:

$5$ divides $x \iff 5$ divides $d_n \iff d_n \in \{0,5\}$ .